# Terraform Using two different map's for resource creation in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We are trying to assign groups to specific roles under projects in gcp. We have a defined map for gcp project related variables

```
project_details = {
  "test-project-1" = {
    project_id   = "test-project-1"
    project_name = "test-project-1"
  }
   "test-project-2" = {
    project_id   = "test-project-2"
    project_name = "test-project-2"
  }
}
```

We have another map defined with roles and members , this is pretty static.

```
role_bind = {
  "billing_admin" = {
   name = "roles/billing.admin"
   member = ["group:gcp-******"]
  }
   "billing_viewer" = {
   name = "roles/billing.viewer"
   member = ["group:gcp-******"]
  }
}
```

We would like to use google_project_iam_member resource to loop through the project id's using the mapped variable project_details

like

```
    for_each = var.project_details 

    project = each.value.project_id
```

and then for each of the project id we would like to assign the roles using the other map variable role_bind.

Can we achieve that by any means ( for_each within for_each ) ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform doesn't support nested for each or nested count. The two ways this usually gets done is by using a count of `len(var.role_bind) * len(varproject_details)` and finding the elements with modulo, or by using nested comprehensions. Nested comprehensions are more readable, so let's go with that:

```
locals {
    project_role = flatten([for pi : project in var.project_details : 
        [ for ri : role in var.role_details {
            rolename    = role.name
            projectname = project.project_name
            projectid   = project.project_id
            member      = role.member
        }]
    ])
}
```

Then you would use `local.project_role` with a count in your statements.

Comment: @Ayan If it worked, than acceptance of the answer is a good practice.